# Pandas: Update() dataframe issue

Tags: pandas

I am using pandas 0.18 on Suse Enterprise Linux 11 w/ python 2.7.9. I have two tables, A and B.

A contains the following column and types:

```
>>> print a.dtypes
cid     object
bid     int64
li      object
lit     int64
x1      float64
y1      float64
x2      float64
y2      float64
hit_num object
```

B contains the following column and types:

```
>>> print b.dtypes
    cid     object
    li      object
    x1      float64
    y1      float64
    x2      float64
    y2      float64
    hit_num object
```

Now here is a sample dataset for A:

```
cid,bid,li,lit,x1,y1,x2,y2,hit_num
id1,0,m0,1,6775.5711,6102.5771,6775.6051,6102.7731,
id1,0,m0,2,6775.5311,6103.0631,6775.5531,6103.2051,
id1,0,m0,3,6775.6231,6103.0631,6775.6451,6103.2051,
id1,0,m0,4,6775.1631,6103.6571,6775.1971,6103.7451,
```

Now here is a sample dataset for B:

```
cid,li,x1,y1,x2,y2,hit_num    
id1,m0,6775.1631,6103.6571,6775.1971,6103.7451,hello
id1,m0,6775.6231,6103.0631,6775.6451,6103.2051,world
id1,m0,6775.5311,6103.0631,6775.5531,6103.2051,gotta
id1,m0,6775.5711,6102.5771,6775.6051,6102.7731,go
```

I do **A.update(B)**. So I'm expecting B[hit_num] to update A[hit_num] by aligning on columns cid,lid,x1,y1,x2,y2.

So I expect something like this (unless my understanding of update() is wrong?):

```
cid,bid,li,lit,x1,y1,x2,y2,hit_num
id1,0,m0,1,6775.5711,6102.5771,6775.6051,6102.7731,0.018,0.02,0.0269,go
id1,0,m0,2,6775.5311,6103.0631,6775.5531,6103.2051,0.018,0.02,0.0269,gotta
id1,0,m0,3,6775.6231,6103.0631,6775.6451,6103.2051,0.018,0.02,0.0269,world
id1,0,m0,4,6775.1631,6103.6571,6775.1971,6103.7451,0.018,0.02,0.0269,hello
```

However, what I end up getting the below. The 'lit' columns (highlighted in bold) seems to be messed up, and there is a duplicated entry of '1'. This is not present in A. I am wondering why this is happening. I created a small example and tried to reproduce the issue, but was unsuccessful. I get expected results there.

However, in a larger table that I'm running my regression on, I'm seeing this behavior. I've printed table A, table B and A.update(B), and I see the below. I'm not calling any other dataframe operations in between. I.e., pseudocode:

```
print v['les_tables']['foo']
print overlay_tables['foo']
v['les_tables']['foo'].update(overlay_tables['foo'])
print v['les_tables']['foo']
```

I am not totally sure how update works, but I would think it is using some type of equality operator to match columns?  If so, would x1,y1,x2,y2 being float64 be causing any issue? Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I've confirmed the columns to align on are the same name/type in both A/B (see A.dtypes/B.dtypes above).

cid,bid,li,lit,x1,y1,x2,y2,hit_num
id1,0,m0,**1**,6775.5711,6102.5771,6775.6051,6102.7731,0.018,0.02,0.0269,go
id1,0,m0,**3**,6775.5311,6103.0631,6775.5531,6103.2051,0.018,0.02,0.0269,gotta
id1,0,m0,**2**,6775.6231,6103.0631,6775.6451,6103.2051,0.018,0.02,0.0269,world
id1,0,m0,**1**,6775.1631,6103.6571,6775.1971,6103.7451,0.018,0.02,0.0269,hello

Comment: `update` aligns on indices, not columns.

Comment: Thanks. Will investigate merge()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
In [73]: df = (A.set_index(['cid','li','x1','y1','x2','y2'])
   ....:        .drop(['hit_num'], axis=1)
   ....:        .join(B.set_index(['cid','li','x1','y1','x2','y2']))
   ....:        .reset_index()
   ....:      )

In [74]: df
Out[74]:
   cid  li         x1         y1         x2         y2  bid  lit hit_num
0  id1  m0  6775.5711  6102.5771  6775.6051  6102.7731    0    1      go
1  id1  m0  6775.5311  6103.0631  6775.5531  6103.2051    0    2   gotta
2  id1  m0  6775.6231  6103.0631  6775.6451  6103.2051    0    3   world
3  id1  m0  6775.1631  6103.6571  6775.1971  6103.7451    0    4   hello
```